Dynamic resource names in kotlin/Android, is this possible?
I have a viewpager2 with five items. I wanted each item to have its own resource name (res_name in the view hierarchy, called via R.id. in code) that was unique. I can accomplish this like so:
res/values/id.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="view_pager_item_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="view_pager_item_2" type="id"/>
    <item name="view_pager_item_3" type="id"/>
    <item name="view_pager_item_4" type="id"/>
    <item name="view_pager_item_5" type="id"/>
</resources>

ViewPagerFragment.kt:
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        arguments?.takeIf { it.containsKey(ARG_OBJECT) }?.apply {
            binding.textViewPagerItem.text = "${getInt(ARG_OBJECT)}"
            when (getInt(ARG_OBJECT)) {
                1 -> binding.textViewPagerItem.id = R.id.view_pager_item_1
                2 -> binding.textViewPagerItem.id = R.id.view_pager_item_2
                3 -> binding.textViewPagerItem.id = R.id.view_pager_item_3
                4 -> binding.textViewPagerItem.id = R.id.view_pager_item_4
                5 -> binding.textViewPagerItem.id = R.id.view_pager_item_5
            }
        }
    }

This works, but it seems messy and inefficient. What if instead of a mere 5 items, I had 1000 items?

If you had 1000 items, it is very unlikely that you would be hardcoding everything.

Right, so how can the above be done, without the manual hardcoding? Without this code, each item will have identical ids.

I do not know why you need these IDs, and specifically why they need to be resource IDs. Since there is no resource at that ID, any attempt to look up a resource with that ID will fail. It would seem simpler to just use getInt(ARG_OBJECT) as the actual ID. What is the objective of using generated resource IDs, versus some more conventional numbering scheme?

Resource IDs are used heavily in Espresso UI testing. It is useful to be able to run a test that checks that item 15 has the right content, and can easily be found with a predictable resource ID such as R.id.view_pager_item_15.

You cannot do R.id.view_pager_item_15 dynamically. That is a compile-time generated value. A dynamically-generated resource value, by definition, is not predictable, and it cannot be referenced by an R.id constant.

That seems to be the case.

In your case you need Dynamic ID generation within your Pager Adapter as adding 1000 items like this is not a logical way and generate lots of boilerplate code.
1. Dynamic ID Generation:
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    private var currentId = R.id.view_pager_item_base  

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val newFragment = ViewPagerFragment()
        newFragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putInt("position", position)
            currentId++  // increment this
            putInt("id", currentId)
        }
        return newFragment
    }

    override fun getCount() = 1000  

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return "Item $position" 
    }
}

2. Custom View as per Layout Item's Position:
class MyItemView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
    // ... your old code
  
    fun bindData(position: Int) {
        // Update view content based on item position
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.your_view_pager_id)
    val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)  
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
}

Note :
Consider using data binding or view binding as they handle referencing views without needing separate IDs.

Update 1
private val viewPagerItemPrefix = "view_pager_item_"

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    val newFragment = ViewPagerFragment()
    val newFragmentId = "$viewPagerItemPrefix$position"
    newFragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
        putInt("position", position)
        val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(newFragmentId, "id", context?.packageName)
        putInt("id", resourceId)
    }
    return newFragment
}

In Fragment use it like this :
class ViewPagerFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false)

        val fragmentId = arguments?.getInt("id") ?: return view
        // Use fragmentId for any view lookups within the fragment

        return view
    }
}


https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/PagerAdapter
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding


This block looks like it just throws it a number:
currentId++  // increment this
putInt("id", currentId)
Is it possible to modify this to be a more readable resource ID, such as R.id.view_pager_item_10, where 10 is the position being passed in?

@ZeekAran updated my answer please check
